# Make an attribute required based on param with Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a model with two attributes. One called **userType** and one called **lastName**.

Basically what I want to do is: if userType is `professor` then lastName should be required.

```js
userType: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  enum: ['professor', 'administrator']
},

lastName: {
  type: 'string',
  required: function() {
    return this.userType === 'professor';
  }
},
```

Why can't I pass required as a function? In the [waterline documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#validations) there is even an example with the validation `contains`.

If not possible, does it have any other way to do this? I don't want to create custom validations on the controller, I want to leave everything to the model. Maybe even use the beforeValidate callback.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to sails documentation http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations
You could make your own validations, something like :

```
module.exports = {
  types: {
    isProfessor: function(lastName){
      return (this.userType === 'professor' && !lastName)? false: true;
    }
  },
  attributes:{
    userType: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      enum: ['professor', 'administrator']
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      isProfessor: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, This feature has been removed in Sails 1.0.